# Laravel. q parameter on error

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4

Wihout changing `route.php` if I go here `http://example.com/test` I get standard `NotFoundHttpException`, but with a slash at the end `http://example.com/test/` Laravel redirects to `http://example.com/test?q=%2Ftest%2F`. How can I disable that redirect?

Answer (score 1):

Turn on "AllowEncodedSlashes" directive in Apache :

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    AllowEncodedSlashes On
</VirtualHost>
```

Turning on this directive tells the web server to allow encoded slashes in URLs.

Bye